# Add a dimmension (other than "1")

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a matrix `matrix1` like

```
[[80 80 80 80]
 [ 0 50  0  0]
 [ 0  0 50  0]
 [ 0  0  0 50]
 [30 30 30 30]]
```

which is shape `(5,4)` and I do `matrix2=matrix[...,np.newaxis]` I get a matrix with shape:
`(5,4,1)`

My question is, how can I get a matrix of shape `(5,4,n)` with n being any number other than 1?

Comment: Have a look at NumPy's `tile` or `repeat` functions.

Comment: Adding a size 1 dimension doesn't change the number of elements, so can be done with a reshape or the `newaxis` indexing.  But adding `n` requires some sort of replication, making the array larger.